# Polygon shape usercontrol

Tags: wpf, controls, polygon, shapes

Is there any way to set style for  my UserControl to look like polygon, for example triangle or sth more sophisticated? I was reading that in WPF there is almost no limits when it comes to modifing graphical interface

Answer (score 1):

WPF has a "lookless" approach to controls and UI. This allows the developer to strongly separate the business logic from the UI logic and also helps to lend itself to MVVM.  What this means for you is that you can use a control template or style to redefine the look of your control.  To name a couple of options, you can use an image, or you could use a Path element. choose whatever works best for you.  Path has the benefit of being a "vector" drawing that will resize automatically-like.  [Here](http://sachabarber.net/?p=354) is a nice article on WPF and "lookless" controls.